# Linear Algebra, Finite v.s., basis, range, and proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Suppose $T∈L(V,W)$ and $w_1, ⋯⋯, w_m$ is a basis of range T. Prove that there exist $\varphi_1,\dots, \varphi_m∈ L(V,F)$ such that $Tv=\varphi_1(v)w_1+ \dots +\varphi_m(v)w_m$ for every $v∈V$.

Comment: Honestly, I struggle with existence proofs. When I see them, I want to show that there is a specific one that I can define, and I have struggled with that concept. I interpret this question as wanting me to prove more specifically that since there is a basis that spans every element in the Range of T, then that and a set of elements mapped by $\phi$ make up the range of T. I struggle with knowing what to put on paper in order to cover all the bases in a convincing proof. does this help you understand where I am coming from? @helloworld112358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\mathcal{W}=\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ denote the basis of $\text{range}(T)$.
For each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, let $\widehat{\mathcal{W}_i}=\mathcal{W}\setminus\{w_i\}$ and let $\Pi_i:W\longrightarrow W$ be the projection onto $\text{span}\big(\{w_i\}\big)$ along $\text{span}$$\left(\widehat{\mathcal{W}_i}\right)$.
Observe that $\text{span}\big(\{w_i\}\big)\oplus\,\text{span}$$\left(\widehat{\mathcal{W}_i}\right)=\text{range}(T)$ is a direct sum, so this is a well-defined projection.

Notice that if $Tv=\varphi_1(v)w_1+ \dots +\varphi_m(v)w_m$, then $\Pi_i(Tv)=\varphi_i(v)w_i$. Do you think you can conclude?

Comment: Two Qs: 1. Are you assuming that the $rangT=W$- and can that be done? 2. Why can it be assumed that the span $\{w_i\}$ and span$\left(\widehat{\mathcal{W}_i}\right)$ is a direct sum? Isn't it possible that an element in the span of $\{w_i\}$ could be in the span of $\left(\widehat{\mathcal{W}_i}\right)$? why or why not? @fimpellizieri

Comment: Oops. That assumption is indeed incorrect; I had misread the question. That said, this does not change much of the reasoning. I will fix the answer. If you still have any doubts, please let me know.